# Unable to generate keys for openvpn using easy-rsa

Tags: raspbian, openvpn

I've been following a tutorial to set up my Raspberry Pi to run OpenVPN (I'm quite new to the Pi and networking, and this seemed to be a fun intro project). However, I've run into a road block when trying to generate keys using easy-rsa. I've edited the `vars` file to point to the `easy-rsa` directory, but whenever I try to source the `vars` file, I get the following message:

```
-bash: /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa: Is a directory
-bash: /whichopensslcnf: No such file or directory
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /keys
```

`/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa` is the location of the directory, so I find the first line to be a bit redundant. Also, the `/whichopensslcnf` file is clearly right there inside the directory.

Any advice or pointers would be much appreciated.

#### UPDATE #1

The tutorial can be found here: https://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing/

`source ./vars` is the command being given that results in the error.

```
# easy-rsa parameter settings

# NOTE: If you installed from an RPM,
# don't edit this file in place in
# /usr/share/openvpn/easy-rsa --
# instead, you should copy the whole
# easy-rsa directory to another location
# (such as /etc/openvpn) so that your
# edits will not be wiped out by a future
# OpenVPN package upgrade.

# This variable should point to
# the top level of the easy-rsa
# tree.
export EASY_RSA="`/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa`"

#
# This variable should point to
# the requested executables
#

export OPENSSL="openssl"
export PKCS11TOOL="pkcs11-tool"
export GREP="grep"


# This variable should point to
# the openssl.cnf file included
# with easy-rsa.
export KEY_CONFIG=`$EASY_RSA/whichopensslcnf`

# Edit this variable to point to
# your soon-to-be-created key
# directory.
#
# WARNING: clean-all will do
# a rm -rf on this directory
# so make sure you define
# it correctly!
export KEY_DIR="$EASY_RSA/keys"

# Issue rm -rf warning
echo NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on $KEY_DIR

# PKCS11 fixes
export PKCS11_MODULE_PATH="dummy"
export PKCS11_PIN="dummy"

# Increase this to 2048 if you
# are paranoid.  This will slow
# down TLS negotiation performance
# as well as the one-time DH parms
# generation process.
export KEY_SIZE=2048

# In how many days should the root CA key expire?
export CA_EXPIRE=3650

# In how many days should certificates expire?
export KEY_EXPIRE=3650
# These are the default values for fields
# which will be placed in the certificate.
# Don't leave any of these fields blank.
export KEY_COUNTRY="US"
export KEY_PROVINCE="CA"
export KEY_CITY="SanFrancisco"
export KEY_ORG="Fort-Funston"
export KEY_EMAIL="me@myhost.mydomain"
export KEY_OU="MyOrganizationalUnit"

# X509 Subject Field
export KEY_NAME="EasyRSA"

# PKCS11 Smart Card
# export PKCS11_MODULE_PATH="/usr/lib/changeme.so"
# export PKCS11_PIN=1234

# If you'd like to sign all keys with the same Common Name, uncomment the 
KEY_C$
# You will also need to make sure your OpenVPN server config has the 
duplicate-$
# export KEY_CN="CommonName"
```

Line 14 is the only one I've modified.

**Update #2**

Thanks to sim, I was able to move past this initial problem, but now when I try to issue the `./clean-all` command, I'm told to source the `vars` file even though I've already done that.

```
pi@cympi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa $ source ./vars
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /etc/openvpn/easy- 
rsa/keys
pi@cympi:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa $ sudo ./clean-all
Please source the vars script first (i.e. "source ./vars")
Make sure you have edited it to reflect your configuration.
```

I've gone 'round and 'round a couple times but I can't seem to get past this point.

Comment: It will be a lot easier for us to help you if you tell us (1) the identity of the tutorial you’re using, (2) the content of your `vars` file (you may, of course, redact any sensitive information), and (3) the exact commands you are running when you get into trouble. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

This line is attempting to run this:

```
export EASY_RSA="`/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa`"
```

Notice the back ticks around `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa`. These will try and run this as a command. Looking at the guide that line is shown like this:

```
export EASY_RSA=”/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa”
```

Comment: Ok awesome! Good eye. Those backticks were there in the file when I opened it. So those marks tell the shell to interpret that line as a command instead of a file path? This fixed the current problem, but I've encountered another roadblock in the next step. I'll update the question to elaborate.